# If I have a battery that provides a high current at almost constant voltage, how do I use it to power other components that require lower currents?

Tags: raspberry-pi, lipo

I have a drone which is powered by a 2200mAh 11.1V 40C/80C LiPo Battery. I want to power a Raspberry Pi 3 B and a video transmitter (TS832) that is rated at 220mA at 12V. Do I need to add resistors or other components to ensure that the the transmitter and the Pi are protected from high current? If so, in what configuration?

Comment: Is the Raspberry Pi fine with being powered from 11.1 V?

Comment: Thought experiment: In your house you have a 100 W lamp and a 10 W lamp both rated for the supply voltage in your country. Do you need to add resistors or other components to ensure that the 10 W lamp is protected from high current?

Comment: Hope you have some spare Raspberry Pis, which need 5.1 volts.

Comment: You can with a DC/DC converter. But the most important muck-up to avoid is sharing supply wires between motors and computer and suffering voltage drop from the motors and browning out the comp.  The computer's supply wires should go all the way back to the battery, even if that means paralleling the motor supply wires.

Comment: @swineone I was going to use a voltage divider circuit or a voltage regulator to get the voltage to acceptable levels for the Pi. I was worried about the high current but I guess that's not an issue.

Comment: @Transistor that makes sense. I just wanted to check before hooking up the battery because I'm on a tight budget in terms of both time and money and I can't afford to replace any burnt components.

Comment: @vik: Good, but read the other comments carefully. Resistors will not **regulate** voltage (maintain constant voltage while the load current varies). Use a proper voltage converter and make sure that the motor current doesn't pass through the same wires as the computer power.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it appears in addition to powering the drone, you also need to power an RPi and a transmitter.

The transmitter requires 12V so the 11.1V battery may not have sufficient voltage. You should check the transmitter functions correctly with this battery.

The RPi will need a 5V supply so I suggest you use a simple voltage regulator (LM7805) or a buck converter (something like [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B076P4C42B?tag=duckduckgo-ffab-20&linkCode=osi&th=1&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076P4C42B)) to drop the 11.1V from the battery. The Rpi will likely need 500-800 mA (see https://raspi.tv/2018/how-much-power-does-raspberry-pi-3b-use-power-measurements for a rough idea).

Your question does not seem to imply any interconnection between the transmitter and the Rpi so I have considered them independently above.

I would test this all on the ground (remove the props) to check it works safely and get a baseline for the flying time. The RPi is using a substantial part of your current budget.